# How to run a create a process in a new Linux namespace

Tags: python, linux-namespaces

I am trying to create a child process with Python under a new [Linux namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html). But checking the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) it does not seem as though Python actually has an API to do so. The closest thing I found is the `unshare` method in the `os` module ([here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.unshare)). But that seems to require these steps:

1. Create a child process in the same namespace as the current parent
2. Run unshare isolate the child process
3. Run the command(s) we wanted in the child process

That's not quite the same as creating an isolated process to start with. Is there indeed no simple API in Python for this?

As an example, here is the analogous code in Go:

```
cmd := exec.Command(...)
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr {
    Cloneflags: syscall.CLONE_NEWUTS
}
cmd.Run()
```

The question is how to achieve the same with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other nice Python API for this. `os.unshare()` and `os.setns()` are currently the only APIs for manipulating namespaces (since Python 3.12). [The feature request](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95023) also mentions this:

> As for now, changing to a different namespace is really messy, one must use ctypes, and call libc functions to do so.
> I think implementing setns and unshare functions will make working with namespaces in Python much easier

You could of course manually issue a `clone` syscall with `CLONE_NEWxxx` flags either through `ctypes` (loading the C library), but that would be pretty messy and definitely unsafe as it wouldn't take into account things like internal interpreter locks etc.

Comment: My research of docs was coming to the same answer, thanks for confirming. It's a bit unexpected to have no API for this.

Comment: @Andrei I think they may want to just keep it simple, at the end of the day there isn't really a noticeable difference between fork + unshare + exec and clone with more flags + exec, other than maybe performance. Since the `os.fork()` is just the POSIX-standard platform-independent function, another API function would have had to be created anyway. The low level semantics of clone are pretty complex so I can see why they probably also wouldn't want to implement that as a Python API. It's already easy to shoot yourself in the foot with `os.fork()`, would be much easier with a `os.clone()` :')